# IIS - How to use appcmd to add cache control rules to ARR?

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr, appcmd

We are using IIS/ARR to act as a reverse proxy which is deployed on Windows Azure, as part of the role startup  a CMD file runs which handles all of the configuration.

eg: %appcmd% set config -section:webFarms /-"[name='mywebfarm']" /commit:apphost

I am having a lot of trouble finding a way to create Cache Control Rules, as shown in [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/651/manually-override-cache-control-directives-using-application-request-routing/) via APPCMD

I've searched through all the config paths I can think of but cannot find any reference to cache control rules (even the ones I create manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided via a crosspost this on the Microsof IIS forums.

http://forums.iis.net/p/1183541/2004589.aspx#2004589

You can generate the appcmd command by using Configuration Editor

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Click Configuration Editor icon on server level
3. Expend the section treeview->Select "system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules"
4. Add a rule
5. Close the dialog windows
6. Click Generate Script in right Actions pane)